# How to load views without segue?

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I'm using Storyboard and I'm wondering if there is a way to perform transitions (animated or not) without "segue".

**Can I put programmatically transitions between my different ViewsController?**

Comment: That's the problem with today's iOS "developers"... Some apparently don't know if it's possible to do something without Interface "Shitty" Builder... See man, I've never used it. I have made several apps and tweaks. From code. Written by hand.

Comment: Ignore @user529758. It's great to understand how to do what it does with just code (and that might be the right path for your situation), but Interface Builder is the right way to go with most projects. If you ever hope to work on a professional development team, you'll need to know how to use IB properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

(And it should not be possible other than using code. This is programming, not graphics design - that's the work of graphics designers.)

UIView has several methods to enable animations and transitions. The most easier to use yet most powerful (read: customizable) is

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    animations:(void (^)(void))animations
    completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

for animations, and

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView
    toView:(UIView *)toView
    duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
    completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

You can find them in [Verse 15 of The Bible.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Comment: @Jean-Benoist no problem :) You asked, at least, to know something new :)